# attach an image to email

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, activexobject

I am trying to attach an image to activex email. I can add this attachment from the URL as www.examle.com/example.jpeg however I want to add my variable which is taken from canvas. You can see my codes below. Could you help me to add this image as attachement? Any other client side method is ok?
Thank you.

```
 var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

 var objO = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application');     
 var objNS = objO.GetNameSpace('MAPI');     
 var mItm = objO.CreateItem(0);     
 mItm.Display(img);     
 mItm.To = "aaa@bbb.com";
 mItm.Subject = "email";
 mItm.Body = document.getElementById("listbox").value;
 mItm.Attachments.Add("img");
 mItm.GetInspector.WindowState = 2;
```